# MYSQL 5.7.18 TRIGGER: trigger_order: { FOLLOWS | PRECEDES } other_trigger_name not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would just like to know how to run/create trigger with follows or precedes syntax. I followed the format yet it's not working.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `sample`$$
DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `the_trigger`$$

 CREATE TRIGGER `the_trigger`
 AFTER INSERT ON `accountcodes`
FOR EACH ROW **PRECEDES sample_trigger**

BEGIN
END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, please include the exactly text of the error message.

Comment: The manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html states - Before MySQL 5.7.2, there cannot be multiple triggers for a given table that have the same trigger event and action time. Maybe you can upgrade.

Comment: @P.Salmon, 5.7.18 is after 5.7.2. See the progression at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/

Comment: @Bill Karwin 'course it is bit of a brain freeze there thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7fEgbjaWXncnmGbz92PFgG/0).